# ASP.NET: How do I get the current user without call Membership.GetUser()?

Tags: asp.net

How do I get the current user without call Membership.GetUser()? I don't want to call this method because it makes a round-trip to the database.

I tried Page.User, but this doesn't return a MembershipUser object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need the user's username, then just call `User.Identity.Name`. If you need other information about the `MembershipUser`, then you'll can't avoid that trip to database (unless as  CResults pointed out, store the object in session).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered storing it in an encrypted state in your session object?

Call `GetUser` once, store the result in the session and from then on get the value from the session object.

Comment: Why the hell would it be encrypted in the Session?

Answer (score 1):

when user is logged in. you can `User.Identity.Name` . you can check with `if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)` and User.Identity.Name. This might help you.